# Advantages of Hibernate Callbacks

Tags: hibernate, callback

What are the advantages of Hibernate Callbacks over traditional approach? Are there any scenarios where it affects the performance?

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to guess what you mean with *traditional approach*. If you mean compared to "old" hibernate interceptors, main advantage is portability.

If you mean implementing event handling 100% yourself,
main advantage is that callbacks give you easily accessible and relatively well specified hooks to the events. Easy access saves you from burden of implementing same functionality by yourself. Use of well documented and in the case of JPA even quite well specified API, instead of home grown implementation is usually better choice. Using standard building blocks makes code easier to understand for next developer.

How much callbacks affect performance depend about how heavy operations are done in callback methods. Extensive logging or some other I/O operations like auditing against data in database can of course cause significant performance hit.